# Apollo Client - Error: Could not find query inside query map

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollostack, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a problem with Apollo Client-React.

I want to send a login request when the user doing click in Log In button.

My code is:

```
// @vendors
import React from 'react';
import { 
  withApollo
} from 'react-apollo';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

class Login extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: 'user1@email.com'
    }
    this.sendRequest = this.sendRequest.bind(this);
  }

  sendRequest() {
    const {
      email
    } = this.state;

    const FETCH_USER = gql`
      query fetchUser($email: String!) {
        user(email: $email) {
          id
        }
      }
    `;
    return this.props.client.query({
      query: FETCH_USER,
      variables: {email: email}
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" className="form-control" id="email" />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" className="form-control" id="password" />
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.sendRequest} className="btn btn-default">Log In</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

Login.propTypes = {
  client: React.PropTypes.instanceOf(ApolloClient).isRequired,
}

export default withApollo(Login);
```

The console shows:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network error: Could not find query inside query map.

Can anybody help me?

> UPDATE:

I used this versions:

- "apollo-client": "^0.6.0"
- "react-apollo": "^0.9.0"